# Creating a Numpy Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am relatively new to Tensorflow. I have my own dataset that I want to create. It contains 60000 numpy arrays (13x44) for input and 60000 output vectors (58x1). One sample can be loaded with the `my_data()` function.

```
def build_dataset(file, param, batch_size):
# Create tf data set
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file, param))
  ds = ds.shuffle(N_shuffle_buffer)
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat().prefetch(N_prefetch)
  return ds

for i in range(len(mfcc_list)):
  m,p=my_data(mfcc_list[i],parameter_list[i])
  mfccs= #??????# 
  parameters= #?????#     

train_ds = build_dataset(mfccs[0:N_training_examples],
                                     parameters[0:N_training_examples], batch_size)
validation_ds = build_dataset(mfccs[N_training_examples:N_training_examples+N_validation_examples],
                                          parameters[N_training_examples:N_training_examples+N_validation_examples],
                                          batch_size)
test_ds = build_dataset(mfccs[N_training_examples+N_validation_examples:],
                                    parameters[N_training_examples+N_validation_examples:], batch_size)
```

My understanding is that I need to create 2 tensors that contain:

1. all my input arrays and
2. all output vectors.

But I am unsure which of tensorflow functions will do this most efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two lists:

```
mfccs = []
parameters = []
for i in range(len(mfcc_list)):
  m,p=my_data(mfcc_list[i],parameter_list[i])
  mfccs.append(m)
  parameters.append(p)
```

Comment: Great. That works! Now my dataset looks like this: <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 13, 44), (None, 58)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float64)>. When I run model.fit() it gives me an error because of an infinite dataset. Why is that?

Comment: @Flitschi great ! please accept the answer

Comment: sorry did you read my message? Shouldnt my dataset be finite now?

Comment: @Flitschi what is the error message ? add the code of your `.fit()` call. Create a new question